# Increase index.max_result_window ElasticSearch 6+

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.3.4

I'm using Magento 2.3.4 Cloud Commerce with ElasticSearch 6+.

I want to increase `max_result_window` to `200000` instead of `100000` in following

```
http://localhost:9200/magento2_product_1_v2/_settings
```

[image]

I've tried to following in `.magento.env.yaml`

```
stage:
  deploy:
    ELASTICSUITE_CONFIGURATION:
      indices_settings:
        max_result_window: 500000
```

But not worked, Then I tried following in custom module `di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Search\Model\Search\PageSizeProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pageSizeBySearchEngine" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="elasticsearch6" xsi:type="number">200000</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

But that didn't work too.

Lastly I found that, This file `Magento\MagentoCloud\Config\SearchEngine\ElasticSuite` is creating ES Template while reindexing so is there anyways to override or is there any otherway by using which I can set the `[index.max_result_window]` to `200000`?

Let me know if any more information is require.

Comment: did you find a fix for this problem?

Comment: @Tjitse I had to override the default ES module.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute the below command to update max_result_window in the required magento-cloud environment:

curl -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/<index_name>/_settings" -d '{ "index" : { "max_result_window" : 30000 } }' -H "Content-Type: application/json"

Answer (score 0):

There are two things we need to do

1. Set the max_result_window using below command
   curl -s -XPUT localhost:9200/*template/template_1 -d '{"template": "magento2**", "order": 0, "settings": {"max_result_window":"40000"}}'
2. There are two potin to set pageSizeProvider

   1. Create a di.xml and set the PageSizeProvider to 40000
      Example : If we are using elasticsearch7 then

```
    <type name="Magento\Search\Model\Search\PageSizeProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="pageSizeBySearchEngine" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="elasticsearch7" xsi:type="number">40000</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

2. In my case, we have created an admin setting where we have to allow the admin to set the limit.

Created a plugin to achieve this.

```
  <type name="Magento\Search\Model\Search\PageSizeProvider">
        <plugin name="afterGetMaxPageSize" 
               type="[VendorName]\[Namespace]\Plugin\Model\Search\PageSizeProvider" 
               sortOrder="1" 
/>
  </type>
```

```
 public function aftergetMaxPageSize(CorePageSizeProvider $subject, $result) : int
    {
        $pageSize = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'moduleName_catalog/search/page_size',
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
        if ($pageSize) {
            return (int)$pageSize;
        }

        return (int)$result;
    }
}
```